# How to tell where site content is being pulled from when it is loaded through javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to scrape some snow data from the mt bachelor website to further analyze and make predictions for avalanches from this page: https://www.mtbachelor.com/the-mountain/weather-operations/conditions-report/live-24-hour-weather

However when I click to view page source, none of the data is there. So I am assuming it is being pulled in from javascript some how.

I want to use php and curl to parse the page and save the snow data into a database. I know how to do that part. However since the page that I want to access does not show the data in the source code, is there a way to still scrape that information?

Comment: Open your browser's debugging tools and observe the network tab.  Requests made by the page will show up there.

Comment: I tried that but still not sure what to look for, here is a screen shot: https://snipboard.io/CpPvMd.jpg it all looks like it is coming from youtube? @David

Comment: Reverse-engineering can be difficult.  You can try to isolate only the XHR requests, search and filter, etc.  We can't even really guarantee that the data you're looking for is necessarily there, and we certainly can't guarantee that it will be easy to find or isn't directly obfuscated to prevent exactly what you're doing.  If this process becomes prohibitively difficult then you might try a different approach, rendering the page with an in-code browser engine (headless browser) so it more closely approximates the in-browser experience and scraping that result.

Comment: i guess i could just email the company and see if they would provide an easier access point to the data :)

Comment: Good idea. A lot of companies provide APIs these days

Comment: A quick look at Network tab while the page loads reveals an XHR request with a JSON response to https://www.mtbachelor.com/api/v1/dor/weather. There are endpoints for sensors, status and conditions too. There doesn't appear to be any requirement for an API key. Good luck